# Is there a way to cast columns by data types without naming the columns specifically?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

Can we replace all columns of a specific data-type to be replaced by a different datatype? For instance, if we have a column in DF as `decimal(38,10)`, can there be a blanket/generic statement to cast all such columns to a different datatype (like integer)

I am aware of using `withColumn` and specifying `column names` to cast them, but in our use case we have thousands of tables with hundreds of columns. There are also valid columns in decimal, which I would like to keep as it is, like `decimal(10,2)` and such. Only a set of columns are getting defaulted to `decimal(38,10)` because they are defined in source system as `NUMERIC` without precision (Oracle). Anything defined as `NUMERIC(10,2)` etc works fine, but just `NUMERIC` gets loaded into target with 10 decimal places.

Solution is to cast them, but there are too many tables/columns involved to do it by name of each and every column. Any generic/blanket way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method for this.

However, if you already have df you can apply a simple function (not UDF) like below, but I don't know whether its performance would work for you or not.

```py
columns = ["language","users_count"]
data = [("Java", 20000), ("Python", 100000), ("Scala", 3000)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

# df.dtypes
# [('language', 'string'), ('users_count', 'bigint')]


def convert_data_types(df):
    for i in df.dtypes:
        if i[1] == "bigint":
            df = df.withColumn(i[0], df[i[0]].cast("string"))
        return df

df = convert_data_types(df)

# df.dtypes
# [('language', 'string'), ('users_count', 'string')]
```

You can use any data type pairs which are compatible to convert each other.